# How to collect JSON object of values from checkboxes, using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to create some kind of small contact table for users, where they can select when is more comfortable to contact them. I have 7 days and 3 conditions - Morning/Afternoon/Evening.

I'm trying to collect this kind of object, to send it to the server -

```
{"SUNDAY":["MORNING"],"MONDAY":["EVENING","MORNING"]}
```

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<tr>
<td class="table-headline">Morning</td>
<td>                                
    <label class="label-check">
        <input id="morning1" name="morning" type="checkbox" value="SUNDAY">
</label>   
</td>
<td>                                
    <label class="label-check">
        <input id="morning2" name="morning" type="checkbox" value="MONDAY">
</label>   
</td>
<td>                                
    <label class="label-check">
        <input id="morning3" name="morning" type="checkbox" value="TUESDAY">
</label>   
</td>
<td>                                
    <label class="label-check">
        <input id="morning4" name="morning" type="checkbox" value="WEDNESDAY">
</label>   
</td>
<td>                                
    <label class="label-check">
        <input id="morning5" name="morning" type="checkbox" value="THURSDAY">
</label>   
</td>
<td>                                
    <label class="label-check">
        <input id="morning6" name="morning" type="checkbox" value="FRIDAY">
</label>   
</td>
<td>                                
    <label class="label-check">
        <input id="morning7" name="morning" type="checkbox" value="SATURDAY">
</label>   
</td>
```

I have three similar lines for each condition. It is not a problem, to detect, if checkbox checked or not, i don't know how to collect in JSON this data after checking.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). It's either a JavaScript object or a JSON formatted string. And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it (assuming the checkboxes are wrapped in a form element):

```
var data = $('form').serializeArray(),
    obj = {};

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   obj[data[i].name] = obj[data[i].name] || [];
   obj[data[i].name].push(data[i].value);
}    

// your JSON string
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

**Edit:** I see that you have the name and values reversed in your sample string. If this is intended and not a typo, simply swap `name` with `value` properties in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an FYI i have created my input for this. its [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qpirate/HqJSS/)

The JS code is as follows

```
$('#btnsubmit').click(function () {

    var obj = [];
    obj.push({
        "MONDAY": GetDetails("MONDAY"),
        "TUESDAY": GetDetails("TUESDAY"),
        "WEDNESDAY": GetDetails("WEDNESDAY"),
        "THURSDAY": GetDetails("THURSDAY"),
        "FRIDAY": GetDetails("FRIDAY"),
        "SATURDAY": GetDetails("SATURDAY"),
        "SUNDAY": GetDetails("SUNDAY"),
    });
$('#output').text(JSON.stringify(obj));
});

function GetDetails(day) {
    var arr = new Array();
    $(':input[value="' + day + '"]').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            arr.push($(this).attr('name'));
        }
    });
        return arr;
}
```

the Output is as follows

```
[{
"MONDAY":["afternoon"],
"TUESDAY":[],
"WEDNESDAY":["morning","afternoon"],
"THURSDAY":[],
"FRIDAY":["morning","afternoon"],
"SATURDAY":[],
"SUNDAY":[]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').on('click',function(){
  // selectors that are checked => $('input:checked').length
  console.log($('input:checked').length)
})
```